# 500 Internal Server Error during login: specific to OnlyMe/Public consent

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

500 Internal Server Error during login: 
 During the login flow for our Facebook App (which is a desktop app), once the user enters the credentials, user will have to choose the maximum privacy level for posts that happen through the app.
 Issue: If user selects either OnlyMe or Public, getting a 500 internal server error from Facebook.
 If user selects Friends, operation is successful.

From Fiddler, below is the difference I see between a successful and a failure call:

API: POST https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth/write HTTP/1.1

For successful call (with Friends consent). I see in the body of the request audience[0][value]=40&private=

For failure, the value isn't set i.e. audience[0][value]=&private=

Any help?

Comment: You should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ and we'll investigate. Make sure to include as much detail as possible: your App ID, your URLs, the error you receive, screenshots etc. In particular, try and include all of the HTTP response headers you receive (including X-FB-Debug).